# How to deep copy linked list object pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to create a function that will create a new linked list given a pointer to an array of integers.

Here's my code, more info below:

```
#include "iostream"


using namespace std;

//Definition for singly-linked list.
struct ListNode {

    //members
    int val;
    ListNode *next;

    //constructor
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}

    //overload assignment operator
    void operator=(const ListNode &right_list ) { 
        val = right_list.val;
        next = right_list.next;
    }   

};

//error here:
//creating new linked list
ListNode*  createNewList(int* x, int length) {
    if (*x == NULL) return NULL;
    ListNode newList = ListNode(-1);
    ListNode* ptr = &newList;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < length) {
        ptr->val = *(x + counter);
        ListNode newElement = ListNode(-1);
        ptr->next = &newElement;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        counter++;
    }
    ListNode* returnPtr = &newList;
    return returnPtr;
}

int main() {


    //create List contents
    int x [5] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 9};
    int* y = x;

    //create list: doesn't work.
    ListNode* newList = createNewList(y, 5);

    cout << "debug test: neList first val is " << newList->val << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With gdb i found that the error is on line:

ptr->next = &newElement;

After the while loop the list has the elements {2, -1, -1, -1, -1}. I believe this is because I'm just setting ptr->next to the address of newElement, instead of creating a new instance of a ListNode identical to newElement and setting ptr->next to it.

But I thought that to avoid this, and to make sure that the '=' sign produces a deep copy, I just have to overload the assignment operator in the ListNode class, which I did.

Also, the value of returnPtr->val right before the end of the createNewList fn is 2 (i verified this with gdb), but the cout statement prints different values for each time, so its some form of undefined behavior. I don't understand the cause.

If I research and find anything new I'll share. Also i can give more info on request. I really wanna understand the pointer move semantics, so links to other situations that may be applicable or articles will go a long way :)

Thanks for reading :) any info is appreciated!

Comment: Why didn't you create a linked list class, where it looks something like this `class LinkedList { private ListNode *root; public: addData(int val); }`?  Instead your code tries to awkwardly retrofit linked list functionality into a single node object.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie, thanks for the idea. I'll try the suggestion, it seems intuitively that by adding single linked node elements one at a time instead of adding them all at once the complexity of the while loop is reduced by a lot, it may even avoid the error i posted. I'll attempt it and see. But do you know what is causing the error above?

Comment: `ListNode* returnPtr = &newList; return returnPtr;` -- This returns a pointer to a local variable.  Thus undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your list elements on the stack, so they disappear once you leave the function.

instead of

```
ListNode newElement = ListNode(-1);
```

try

```
ListNode* newElement = new ListNode(-1);
```

E.g.

```
ListNode*  createNewList(int* x, int length) {
    if (x == nullptr) return x;
    ListNode* newList = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode* ptr = newList;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < length) {
        ptr->val = *(x + counter);
        ListNode* newElement = new ListNode(-1);
        ptr->next = newElement;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        counter++;
    }
    return newList;
}
```

This here is unnecessary

```
int x [5] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 9};
int* y = x;

//create list: doesn't work.
ListNode* newList = createNewList(y, 5);
```

You could instead just pass x directly

```
ListNode* newList = createNewList(x, sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x));
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Even the sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x) was pretty beautiful IMHO. The issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
std::list<int> newlist {x, x+length};
```